# Function to dynamically allocate matrix and treats all errors

Tags: c

I have created this function to allocate a matrix dynamically. I would like to know if the function treats all the cases if something goes wrong (I mean free what malloc() has done).

```
void allocate(double*** m, int r, int c){
  int l;
  *m = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*r);
  if(*m == NULL) return;
  for(l=0;l<r;l++){
    (*m)[l] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*c);
    if((*m)[l] == NULL) {
        int l2;
        for(l2=0;l2<l;l2++)
            free((*m)[l2]);
        free(*m);
        *m = NULL;
        return; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of the 3ple pointer, just return from the function. Note that a matrix is an abstract construction. Your code allocates an array of pointer if anything. Oh, and make good use of whitespace, sothatyourcodeisnotunreadable.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Thanks for your advice, I think I should use the 3ple pointer in this case. I cannot return a local pointer.

Comment: Why can't you return a local pointer?

Comment: You can't afford to return a pointer to local (non-static) data, but returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory is safe. Thus `int *function1(void) { int array[] = { 9, 2, 4 }; return array; }` is bad — returning a pointer to local data that goes out of scope when the function returns. `int *function2(void) { int *array = malloc(3 * sizeof(int)); if (array == NULL) return array; array[0] = 0; array[1] = 2; array[2] = 4; return array; }` is returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory and is safe. So is: `int *function3(void) { static int array[] = { 9, 2, 4 }; return array; }`

Comment: I would separate the deallocation into a separate function. You can then reuse it here and when you're finished using the matrix and need to deallocate it.

Comment: As it stands, your code correctly releases all the data that was previously allocated before returning if an allocation error occurs.  You will need a function to release the allocated memory; it will need to know how many rows to release.  You can use that in your error recovery, using `l` as the number of rows to be released.  Note that [Three-star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment — if you have a 3D array, it's hard to avoid three stars, but you could return a `double **` safely, simplifying the notation in the function.

Comment: Also consider the merits of a single allocation of `r * c * sizeof(double)` bytes, and then setting the pointers to point to the right place in that array.  It simplifies the memory release process enormously.

Comment: "I would like to know if the function treats all the cases if something goes wrong" --> It does not correctly handle the corner cases of `r==0` or `c==0` well.

Comment: Use common sense -> "*I cannot return a local pointer*", then how does `malloc()` work? Note that [this comment covers it very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819323/function-to-dynamically-allocate-matrix-and-treats-all-errors?noredirect=1#comment84642812_48819323)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819323/function-to-dynamically-allocate-matrix-and-treats-all-errors#comment84642904_48819323), within broad limits, if your code encounters an allocation error, you correctly release all the data that was allocated prior to the error.

You will need a function to release the allocated memory; it will need to know how many rows to release. You could use that in your error recovery, using `l` as the number of rows to be released.

```
void deallocate(double **matrix, int rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

That does not set the pointer passed in to null; you can use a three-star interface if you insist, but it probably isn't worthwhile (IMO — YMMV).  This can then be used in the allocation code.

```
void allocate(double ***m, int r, int c)
{
    *m = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * r);
    if (*m == NULL)
        return;
    for (int l = 0; l < r; l++)
    {
        (*m)[l] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * c);
        if ((*m)[l] == NULL)
        {
            deallocate(*m, l);
            *m = NULL;
            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

There are those who are fanatical about '[no cast on `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/)' — I am not one of those, but I do make sure my code doesn’t compile in my development environment if `<stdlib.h>` was not included (so there was no declaration of `malloc()` et al viable when it is called).  That makes it safe for user’s too, even if they don’t compile with the rigorous warning/error options I use.

Note too that [Three-star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment.  As suggested in the comments, you could use a different interface:

```
double **allocate(int r, int c)
{
    double **matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * r);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int l = 0; l < r; l++)
    {
        matrix[l] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * c);
        if (matrix[l] == NULL)
        {
            deallocate(matrix, l);
            return NULL; 
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Note that because the allocation (and deallocation) functions use `int` and not `size_t` for the size parameters, you could get negative values.  You could also get zeros provided — but if the size is zero, the code will 'work' safely, but the result will be unusable (no space allocated).

Comment: Nice answer - just curious about the casting part. Anyway I would UV.